# Unable to insert from Meteor method with object

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

Morning folks! Running into some trouble trying to do what should be a simple insert in Meteor, but passing an `object` is killing me.

I have a set of filters on my site that are working, but now I want to save the `selector` of those filters to a collection so that I can quickly pull up documents that match several filters.

The problem seems to be passing an object that contains a saved search. The object does have what Collection2 might see as nested properties ("addresses.state") but I've got "blackbox: true" set on the schema, so I don't know why it would even be looking there...

Here's the whole flow:

Form to save search name:

```
<template name="saveSearch">
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#saveSearchForm" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="saveSearchForm">
      Advanced Search
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="saveSearchForm">
      <div class="well">
        // Display filters from the awesome meteor-tabular-filter package
        {{> expression_filter}}
        <form id="saveSearch" class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="searchName">Save Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchName" id="searchName" placeholder="Search Name">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Template event to call method to insert search:

```
Template.saveSearch.events({
  'submit #saveSearch' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let queries = Session.get("filter_selector"),
        search = {
          name: String(template.find( "[name='searchName']" ).value),
          selector: queries
        };

    console.log('search: ' + JSON.stringify(search));

    Meteor.call( 'insertSearch', search, ( error, response ) => {
      if ( error ) {
        Bert.alert( error.reason, 'warning', 'growl-top-right' );
      } else {
        Bert.alert( 'Search saved', 'success', 'growl-top-right' );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here's a couple of different console.log(); results passed to the method:

```
1) {"name":"Alabama","selector":{"addresses.state":"AL"}}
2) {"name":"Alabama","selector":{"$and":[{"addresses.state":"AL"},{"lastName":"Knapp"}]}}
```

Meteor method to insert search

```
// in both/methods/insert
Meteor.methods({
  insertSearch( doc ) {
    check( doc, Searches.simpleSchema() );

    var defaultProperties = {
      orgId    : Meteor.user().profile.currentOrg,
      createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
      createdAt: moment().toDate()
    };

    newDoc = _.extend(doc, defaultProperties);

    console.log('search to insert: ' + JSON.stringify(newDoc));

    try {
      var searchId = Searches.insert( newDoc, {bypassCollection2: true} );
      console.log('search insert successful');
      return searchId;
    } catch( exception ) {
      console.log('search insert failed');
      throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Search failed to save.');
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a couple of different console.log(); results passed to the insert:

```
1) {"name":"Alabama","selector":{"addresses.state":"AL"},"orgId":"testorg","createdBy":"DHo3vr3fiZbSYBJks","createdAt":"2016-01-28T13:38:27.499Z"}
2) {"name":"Alabama","selector":{"$and":[{"addresses.state":"AL"},{"lastName":"Knapp"}]},"orgId":"testorg","createdBy":"DHo3vr3fiZbSYBJks","createdAt":"2016-01-28T13:42:51.468Z"}
```

And the schema definition for the Searches collection...

```
Searches = new Mongo.Collection( 'searches' );

Searches.allow({
  insert: () => false,
  update: () => false,
  remove: () => false
});

Searches.deny({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true
});

let searchSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    label: 'Search Name',
    type: String
  },
  selector: {
    label: 'Search Criteria',
    type: Object,
    blackbox: true,
    optional: true
  },
  orgId: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    label: "Created By",
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
      return Meteor.userId()
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created At",
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date;
      }
    },
    denyUpdate: true
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Updated At",
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        this.unset();
      } else {
        return new Date;
      }
    }
  }
});

Searches.attachSchema( searchSchema );
```

Lastly, here's an error log from Kadira:

```
message: Search failed to save. [500] 
stack:
Error: Search failed to save. [500]
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.insertSearch (both/methods/insert/searches.js:21:13)
    at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:164:1)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
    at livedata_server.js:708:19
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at livedata_server.js:706:40
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at livedata_server.js:704:46
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/allen/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1u69k2a++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/allen/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1u69k2a++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:171:13)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When you take out the catch block what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @StephenWoods: Thanks for taking a look! I ended up adding `JSON.stringify(queries)` and then `JSON.parse()` to the return helper and got it working. I'll go back though and take a look at the error. Curious why it was happening...